# Delete music directly from iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, music.app

I would like to find a way to delete individual songs from my iPhone and automatically synchronize this deletion in iTunes.

My current workaround is this: Star the songs I don't like anymore with 1 star, synchronize iPhone (takes forever), then delete the songs with 1 star and resync.

Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete songs directly in your music application. Just get the title overview and swipe from one side to the other and a delete button appears.

When you have automatic syncronisation activated in your iTunes, it will automatically sync your music next time you're in the same network with your iTunes computer, your iTunes is started on this computer and your iPhone is locked and wired to the power.

Comment: wouldn't synchornizing with itunes put the deleted songs on my iphone again?

Comment: No, the power of syncronization is that it works into both directions: "[Content is synced between your iOS device and computer to reflect new, updated, or deleted content.](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1386?viewlocale=en_US)"

Comment: I have actually seen this NOT be the case. I have deleted songs directly from my iPhone 5 only to sync with iTunes and have them re-download to the phone. Totally counter intuitive to a 'sync' process.